# Problem with Project R installation

Tags: 14.04, r

I don't know where to put this line in the file. Or is there the possibility to achieve it over the shell somehow? I'm using 14.04.

> INSTALLATION
>
> To obtain the latest R packages, add an entry like
>
> `deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/`
>       or
>
> `deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/`
>       or
>
> `deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu lucid/`
>
> in your /etc/apt/sources.list file, replacing
>   `<my.favorite.cran.mirror>` by the actual URL of your favorite CRAN
>   mirror. See http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html for the list of
>   CRAN mirrors. To install the complete R system, use
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>      `sudo apt-get install r-base`

My mirror would be: `http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/`

Comment: Do you really need the _latest_ version? Version 3.0.2 is available from the standard repository for Ubuntu Trusty (without adding anything to your sources.list file) just by typing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install r-base`

Comment: If one is doing anything bioconductor-related (which by now is a large portion of the R community), one _must_ use the very latest stable R.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. It doesn't matter where exactly, but end of the file is ok.

```
deb http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/ #enabled-manually
```

If you insist on doing this in a terminal, do the following:

```
sudo su 
echo "deb http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/ #enabled-manually" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
exit
```

This will launch a super user session, and append the line to the sources.list file, after which we exit from the super user session.

Then, per the [R installation instructions](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README), one must add the public key of Michael Rutter to secure apt. Execute the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

Then simply do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev`.

Happy R-ing!