# OpenForis Calc / embedded Tomcat won't start

Tags: server, java, tomcat7

Trying to run [OpenForis Calc](http://www.openforis.org/tools/calc.html), embedded Tomcat instance fails.

Error seems to appear here:

```
Apr 17, 2015 2:13:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor 
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /opt/OpenForisCalc/calc-server/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/calc.xml

Apr 17, 2015 2:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal  
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Then if messes up with the rest (this repeats a lot):

```
Apr 17, 2015 2:13:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal 
SEVERE: Context [/calc] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: It went fine. I only got the message when the Tomcat ran and the Software didn't open on Firefox.

Comment: @tohuwawohu It never worked. But i had no error message during the installation.

Comment: I think so. I've never opened postgresql. I have it ONLY for Calc.

Comment: Wait wait... It is stuck. It open Calc... blue screen... Loading bar... but nothing further.

Comment: Many. It get stuck and freezes Firefox. Let me copy it.

Comment: Apr 17, 2015 3:50:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 6 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [spring]
Apr 17, 2015 3:51:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 6 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [spring]
Apr 17, 2015 3:51:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 6 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [spring]
Apr 17, 2015 3:54:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await

Comment: Ok... I restarted and reinstalled Cal... and restarted again. It is the same. Tomcat runs now. Calc opens on Firefox, but remains stuck in the loading. I can see the Plataform (buttons and so), but no interaction.  

Apr 17, 2015 4:15:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Apr 17, 2015 4:15:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 3 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [spring]

Comment: Please check if **JavaScript is enabled** in your browser. With JavaScript **disabled**, the first page of Calc displays about 11 buttons without functionality and some horizontal lines. Alternatively, try to access Calc using Google Chrome or [Chromium](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser/). I assume it isn't a server-side issue any more, but a browser issue.

Comment: JavaScript was enabled. Do you think Calc will automatically recognize Chromium once I install it? Do I have to uninstall Firefox?

Comment: After installing chromium, just open the following URL in chromium: http://localhost:8081/calc - you don't need to uninstall firefox. If it doesn't work, check the calc log (see my answer, i've edited it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *assume* this is because Calc isn't able to access the PostgreSQL database. Double-check if PostgreSQL is running:

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

should return something like

```
9.3/main (port 5432): online
```

If PostgreSQL is running, check the credentials. By default, there's no admin password set for PostgreSQL. Calc assumes `postgres` as admin password, by default. So, if you didn't set a password yet, follow [the instructions to do so](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL#Basic_Server_Setup):

1. Start the postgresql command line client as user postgres:

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql postgres
   ```
2. Inside the client:

   ```
   \password postgres
   ```
3. Now, you can enter the admin password - you should choose a secure one!

If you want to change the password Calc is using (maybe because you've choosen a more secure one): open the following file with your favorite text editor:

```
/opt/OpenForisCalc/calc-server/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/calc.xml
```

and look for a line looking like:

```
<Parameter name="calc.jdbc.adminpassword" value="postgres" />
```

EDIT:

If you still encounter problems, you should check the logs directly. You'll find them in

```
/opt/OpenForisCalc/calc-server/tomcat/logs
```

There should be a log file `calc.log` - check its contents for errors.

Comment: i did what you told me. I get: 9.3/main (port 5432): online

Comment: It does:
2015-04-17 16:14:51,830 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG (DatabaseInitializer.java [isDBInitialized]:56) - Check database initialization: driver=org.postgresql.Driver host=localhost port=5432 user=calc 
2015-04-17 16:14:52,255 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG (DatabaseInitializer.java [isDBInitialized]:61) - Database exists 
2015-04-17 16:15:25,367 [http-apr-8081-exec-5] WARN  (R.java [getJriPath]:86) - Error getting JRI library path from R

Comment: 2015-04-17 16:43:30,320 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG (DatabaseInitializer.java [isDBInitialized]:56) - Check database initialization: driver=org.postgresql.Driver host=localhost port=5432 user=calc 
2015-04-17 16:43:31,309 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG (DatabaseInitializer.java [isDBInitialized]:61) - Database exists 
2015-04-17 16:44:03,985 [http-apr-8081-exec-5] WARN  (R.java [getJriPath]:86) - Error getting JRI library path from R

Comment: Is R installed? Did you tell the Calc installer to use `/usr/lib/R` as R installation directory? Maybe again the full log may provide useful information...

Comment: I did. The full log is too big to paste here. Check this part:
Apr 17, 2015 4:58:40 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Apr 17, 2015 4:58:40 PM org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.jersey.EnunciateJerseyServletContainer configure
INFO: org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.amf.JAXRSProvider not found.

Comment: from the calc.log
2015-04-17 16:58:30,117 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG (DatabaseInitializer.java [isDBInitialized]:56) - Check database initialization: driver=org.postgresql.Driver host=localhost port=5432 user=calc 
2015-04-17 16:58:30,206 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG (DatabaseInitializer.java [isDBInitialized]:61) - Database exists 
2015-04-17 16:58:43,027 [http-apr-8082-exec-1] WARN  (R.java [getJriPath]:86) - Error getting JRI library path from R

Comment: Again, just guessing: rjava isn't available. Try `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava` and restart Calc afterwards.

Comment: For full logfile, use something like http://www.tinyupload.com/ and add a link to the uploaded log. Regarding R: see http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README  and http://askubuntu.com/questions/506560/how-to-install-package-of-r

Comment: It worked!! I need to copy some things we have done here before you delete the questions. ok?

Comment: No problem :-) great to hear that it works now!

Comment: I'll do my best (maybe tomorrow, here's already near midnight...) - btw, regarding the comments - i can only delete my own comments, you should remove your ones if they aren't required any more to understand question and answer.