# Upgrade R on Kubuntu 14.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, r

How can I upgrade my R installation on Kubuntu 14.4 LTS from 3.0.2 to the current 3.2.4?

Something like

```
sudo su
echo "deb http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

or a variation of this won't work - R will stay at 3.0.2.

Comment: see this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/506571/16835

Comment: Actually, this was not the reason... the reason was that I messed up the policy of my apt-get settings regarding which packages to install in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`. ( @amc )