# apt-get install r-base Gives 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, permissions

I am trying to install `r-base` in my just installed Ubuntu 14.04 system.

However, I get the following error (only last few lines of output is shown here):

```
0 upgraded, 70 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 457 kB/71.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 156 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe r-cran-cluster amd64 1.14.4-1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cluster/r-cran-cluster_1.14.4-1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get update --fix-missing`. Before fixing the missing files, I used to get a warning at the end of the `apt-get update` that some key is missing. However, using it with `--fix-missing` solved that error. But still there is error while installing `r-base`.

Through the Software Center, I get the same error with title: Failed to download package files, Check your internet connection. Error is as below.

```
Error: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cluster/r-cran-cluster_1.14.4-1_amd64.deb 403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
```

My internet connection is fine. When I try to open above link in browser, it says "access denied".

How can I get access? Or from where else can I find the same file? I am new to Ubuntu. I found some other problems of 403 forbidden error but none helped me and they were for different specific cases (not like mine).

---

### UPDATE

Trying [this link](https://launchpad.net/~opencpu/+archive/ubuntu/opencpu-1.5/+build/9600489)'s `deb` file using `dpkg` gives output as below

```
darshil@darshil-Lenovo-G580:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i r-cran-cluster_2.0.4-1trusty0_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-cluster.
(Reading database ... 185096 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack r-cran-cluster_2.0.4-1trusty0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-cluster (2.0.4-1trusty0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-cluster:
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-base-core (>= 3.2.5-1trusty0); however:
  Package r-base-core is not installed.
 r-cran-cluster depends on r-api-3; however:
  Package r-api-3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package r-cran-cluster (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r-cran-cluster
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that it was my service provider's problem. For some reason the network at my institute was blocking this single file. So I installed `r-base` from terminal at another network (from another place) and it worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

Try to install r from CRAN. Add

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` then add the key to archive

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

Then everything should be OK

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-recommended rstudio
```

P.S. Don't forget to update repository in `sources.list` after upgrading to a new version of Ubuntu. [List of available versions and some setup instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README).

Comment: Did what you said. New error:  `E: Failed to fetch http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/r-cran-cluster_2.0.4-1trusty0_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`  So basically the same error with CRAN as well. Again, when I open the above deb URL in browser, it shows access denied.

Comment: @DarshilChauhan  `r-base` cannot have missing packages on CRAN. Try `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` and then try to install r-base again.

Comment: Nope, same result. I even tried adding `deb http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/` and adding its key and then updating and installing (Got it from http://askubuntu.com/questions/503270/problem-with-project-r-installation). Still it gives same error for this one also. What could be the cause of this? Could it be that my device or network is blocking this particular `deb` file? Can you try opening the `deb` URL in your browser?

Comment: @DarshilChauhan  While I googled it, I found that there is something strange with the filename. Try again  [this CRAN link](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/r-cran-cluster_2.0.4-1trusty0_amd64.deb). If it still doesn't work take it [from here](https://launchpad.net/~opencpu/+archive/ubuntu/opencpu-1.5/+build/9600489), but this is another build so it's not recommended. Install it manually with sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE_NAME.deb

Comment: I tried your other source, but when I run the `deb` file in the software center, it gives same error: `Failed to fetch http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/r-cran-cluster_2.0.4-1trusty0_amd64.deb 403  Forbidden` Maybe because they are also using CRAN for that file? I also tried it using `dpkg` but that too didn't work. I will put entire output is in the update of the question. Any idea what might be causing this? Someone outside my network tried to go the `deb` files through browser but it showed "Not Found". I don't understand. What is going on?

Comment: @DarshilChauhan  Package name from your linklooks the same as what I found, but the symbol used for "_" is different.  Looks like this version or R is broken both on CRAN and Ubuntu repository. You can try install 32bit version of R that doesn't have this package:  `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`  then `sudo apt-get install r-base:i386`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39089/discussion-between-darshil-chauhan-and-hcl14).

Comment: Tried it. Not working. Ouput:`darshil@darshil-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @DarshilChauhan The error with manually downloaded package is that dpkg wants its dependencies.  `gdebi` does it as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58202/how-to-automatically-fetch-missing-dependencies-when-installing-software-from-d#).  I don't want to move this discussion to chat as someone can find it useful or find a solution while reading this.

Comment: @DarshilChauhan  It says that it has another package to replace ia32-libs. `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`. You also may need to install gdebi: `sudo apt-get install gdebi-core`